# Error when loading WFS layer. Missing coordinate reference system

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, wfs, colombia

I am trying to load several layers from: 
http://idesc.cali.gov.co:8081/geoserver/wfs?

In the window "Add WFS layer" appears EPSG:6249, but after adding appears a second window, "CRS selector", where I cannot find this ID.

[image]

If I click on "Cancel" I always get this error for all layers:

`Download of features for layer idesc:mc_comunas failed or partially failed: Server generated an exception in GetFeature response: org.opengis.referencing.NoSuchAuthorityCodeException: No se ha especificado ninguna autoridad para el código "". El formato esperado es normalmente "AUTORITÉ:NOMBRE". No se ha especificado ninguna autoridad para el código`

How to import this CRS?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct [EPSG:6249](https://www.epsg-registry.org/export.htm?wkt=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::6249) is not one of the supported coordinate reference systems for QGIS.

The [QGIS documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_projections/working_with_projections.html) gives information on how to create a custom coordinate reference system through `Settings > Custom CRS`.

Note, you will need to use [PROJ.4 format](http://proj4.org/parameters.html), you will have to create it yourself, if you cannot find it elsewhere.  Use the EPSG registry report to help you with the parameters.

http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::6249&reportDetail=short&style=urn:uuid:report-style:default-with-code&style_name=OGPDefault%20With%20Code&title=Bogota-MAGNA

Comment: Thank you, i tried this, but the file PROJ.4 format is empty:

http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/8185/

Answer (score 0):

contacted IDESC and found prog.4format file for an equivalent CRS:
SR-ORG:7393

Answer (score 0):

From `C:\OSGeo4W64\share\proj\epsg`: `Unable to translate coordinate system EPSG:6249 into PROJ.4 format.`.

The projection EPSG:6249 uses a parameter called `Projection plane origin height` with a value of 1000 meters. This method is not implemented in PROJ.4/GDAL, and the CRS is therefore not included in PROJ.4 based software like QGIS.

At spatialreference.org, there is a workaround definition [SR-ORG:7393](http://spatialreference.org/ref/sr-org/7393/) with this projection string:

```
+proj=tmerc +lat_0=3.441883333 +lon_0=-76.5205625 +k=1 +x_0=1061900.18 +y_0=872364.63 +a=6379137 +b=6357748.961329674 +units=m +no_defs
```

It substitutes the `projection plane origin height` of 1000m by an ellipsoid with `a` 1000m larger, but with the same flattening as GRS80.

You can define a custom CRS with it, but unfortuantely the WFS server only allows the EPSG code 6249 to be requested.

The only way I found to get the WFS working is to modify the SR database of QGIS in `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\resources`.

I created a SQL file named `Cali.sql` with this content:

```
BEGIN;
INSERT INTO "tbl_srs" ("srs_id", "description", "projection_acronym", "ellipsoid_acronym", "parameters", "srid", "auth_name", "auth_id", "is_geo", "deprecated", "noupdate") VALUES (29456, 'MAGNA-SIRGAS / Cali urban grid', 'tmerc', '', '+proj=tmerc +lat_0=3.441883333 +lon_0=-76.5205625 +k=1 +x_0=1061900.18 +y_0=872364.63 +a=6379137 +b=6357748.961329674 +units=m +no_defs', 6249, 'EPSG', '6249', 0, 0, 0);
COMMIT;
```

There were 29455 records in my `tbl_srs`, so the new one goes into 29456. Then I used the spatialite_gui with

```
Files -> Connecting an existig SQlite DB
```

to connect to `C:\Program Files\QGIS 2.18\apps\qgis\resources\srs.db` and

```
Files -> Advanced -> Execute SQL script
```

to add the Cali.sql.

After that, the WFS loads without errors, fitting to an OpenStreetmap background:

[image]

You have to run this agaian after every QGIS update, and it will not work on external GDAL commands like gdalwarp, and maybe GRASS too.